# Tkinter dropdown menu from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

Instead of having a user input "Job Name", I want it to be a Tkinter drop down menu.

Im guessing the idea will be to append Jobname with the list of names from Table. How will it have it show in the tkinter dropdown?

```
Jobname = []
...
for row in rows:
        data = "%s %s %s %s %s" % (row["Id"], row["Title"], row["Date"], row["Time"], row["Duration"])
        movieList.append(data)
        print data
```

My Code

```
def reportdata():
    clear()
    w11 = Label(fr, text="Job Name : ")
    w11.grid(row=1, column=0)
    listlab.append(w11)
    w22 = Label(fr, text="Job Start Date: ")
    w22.grid(row=2, column=0)
    listlab.append(w22)
    w33 = Label(fr, text="Job End Date: ")
    w33.grid(row=3, column=0)
    listlab.append(w33)

    e11 = Entry(fr, textvariable=jjname)
    e11.grid(row=1, column=1)
    listlab.append(e11)
    e22 = Entry(fr, textvariable=jjdates)
    e22.grid(row=2, column=1)
    listlab.append(e22)
    e33 = Entry(fr, textvariable=jjdatee)
    e33.grid(row=3, column=1)
    listlab.append(e33)

    mbuttonn = Button(fr, text="Generate", command=savexl)
    mbuttonn.grid(row=4, column=3)
    listlab.append(mbuttonn)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You are not showing any attempt to use `OptionMenu` or any data fetching from sql table.

Comment: I have updated it. Please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Please see below for an example of how you can use a `list` to populate a `tkinter` `OptionMenu`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a = [] #creates a list to store the job names in
var = StringVar() #creates a stringvar to store the value of options

for i  in range(20): #fills list with nonsense jobs for troubleshooting
    a.append("Job Name "+str(i))

var.set(a[0]) #sets the default option of options

options = OptionMenu(root, var, *a) #createa an optionmenu populated with every element of the list
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:print(var.get())) #prints the current value of options

options.pack()
button.pack()
```

This uses a `list` to fill out an `OptionMenu` with all of it's elements, then we create a `button` which prints the current value of the `OptionMenu`.

If you can get your SQL imported data into a `list` you can use the same logic as above.